# sql join two tables and get the unique values from one table based on another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following **table1**, in which an `id` could appear multiple times and each time with a unique `name` and the same for `name`, it could appear multiple times and each time with a different `id`.

```
id  name
---------
A2  B6
A3  B2
A3  B400
A5  B100
A7  B200
A8  B300
A8  B2
A8  B3
```

and here is the **table2** in which all of the `id`s from **table1** exist, but not all of the `name`s. And each `id` has a `surname`.

```
id  name    surname
-------------------
A1          Lastname1
A2          Lastname2
A3  B1      Lastname3
A4          Lastname4
A5  B2      Lastname5
A6          Lastname6
A7  B3      Lastname7
A8  B4      Lastname8
A9          Lastname9
A10 B6      Lastname10
```

here is the query result:
- the first column: list of all of the unique `id`s from **table1** PLUS the list of all of the `name`s in **table1** that are not found in the `name` column of **table2**.
- second column: the `surname` of the each element in `id` column of the results table taken from **table2**, all of the `id`s from **table1** have a corresponding surname, but if the `name` from the **table1** was not found in **table2**, then we put the same `name` as the surname.
- third column: if `id` or `name` from the **table1** was found in the **table2**, then the status will be **FOUND**, however if the `name` from **table1** was not found, it will get **NOT FOUND**

```
id      surname     status
---------------------------
A2      Lastname2   FOUND
A3      Lastname3   FOUND   
A5      Lastname5   FOUND   
A7      Lastname7   FOUND   
A8      Lastname8   FOUND   
A10     Lastname10  FOUND   
B100    B100        NOT FOUND
B200    B200        NOT FOUND
B300    B300        NOT FOUND
B400    B400        NOT FOUND
```

Comment: you can use `left join`

Comment: This row does not make sense - `A2      Lastname2   FOUND` -- what are the rules the "allow" this one to be found?

Comment: This is a bit convoluted.  You might want to start by avoiding the use of the column descriptor `id`.  Most of us would think of `id` as unique and `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Next, give the tables descriptive names about what they represent instead of "table1" "table2".  Even using name as a name can be a bit confusing.

Comment: @Hogan row 1 is "found" because ID or NAME from table 1 (row 1 column 1 of table 1 is A2) was "found in table 2" (was in id column of table 2 somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

This is called a left join.  Here is how to apply it to your question:

```
SELECT table1.id, coalesce(table2.surname, table1.name) as surname,
      case when table2.id is null then 'not found' else 'found' end as status
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.name = table2.name
```

---

As @ebyrob pointed out you don't want ids in the first column for non matches:

```
SELECT 
   case when table2.id is null then table1.name else table1.id end as id,
   coalesce(table2.surname, table1.name) as surname,
   case when table2.id is null then 'not found' else 'found' end as status
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.name = table2.name
```

Comment: For starters, the OP is matching `table1.name` against `table2.id`, things digress from there.

Comment: no idea what you mean @ebyrob -- that is not what is shown in the question.  ids all start with "A" and names start with "B" so such a match is not possible.

Comment: Read the description of the desired result.  First column is a list of all the names and ids from the first table.  Later:  "if id or name from the table1 was found in the table2", then FOUND etc.

Comment: @ebyrob -- the rules and example are a bit confused this means one of two things -- a) I don't understand the rules and they make sense once understood b) I don't understand the rules because they are not possible to actually implement in a real system or c) they are badly explained but are the same thing everyone always wants to do when they are working with SQL.  I'm assuming "C" -- I might be wrong, I've been wrong before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, in this case, it's definitely not C.  see the cross posting here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244823/sql-how-to-combine-three-queries-from-two-tables-into-one-query  The result set is pretty carefully crafted and matches at least some of the convoluted logic.  The only thing I'm not sure about is if the OP is trying to achieve something useful or just playing a twisted form of code golf.

Comment: @ebyrob -- I'll note that the expected results there are different than this question and he did not update this question -- the expected results there specifically don't include the A2 row, the one I said did not make sense in my comments on this question!  I'm done with this joker.