# sql how to combine three queries from two tables into one query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following two tables:

**Table1**

```
id  name
---------
A3  B2
A3  B400
A5  B100
A7  B200
A8  B6
A8  B2
A8  B3
```

and **Table2**

```
id  name    company
-------------------
A1          company1
A2          company2
A3  B1      company3
A4          company4
A5  B2      company5
A6          company6
A7  B3      company7
A8  B4      company8
A9          company9
A10 B6      company10
```

I am launching three queries to get what i want, but with three queries. My question is how can I do all this in one query and in more efficient way?

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id as ID,
        t2.company as Company,
        'FOUND' AS status
 FROM   table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2
          ON t1.id = t2.id
group by ID
```

*query 1 result:*

```
ID  Company     Status
-----------------------
A3  company3    FOUND
A5  company5    FOUND
A7  company7    FOUND
A8  company8    FOUND
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id as ID,
        t2.company as Company,
        'FOUND' AS status
 FROM   table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2
          ON t1.name = t2.name
group by ID
```

*query 2 result:*

```
ID  Company     Status
-----------------------
A5  company5    FOUND
A10 company10   FOUND
A7  company7    FOUND
```

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT t1.name as ID,
        t1.name as Company,
        'NOT FOUND' AS status
 FROM   table1 t1
  WHERE  t1.name NOT IN (SELECT t2.name
                                FROM   table2 t2)
GROUP BY ID
```

*query 3 result:*

```
ID  Company     Status
-----------------------
B400    B400    NOT FOUND
B100    B100    NOT FOUND
B200    B200    NOT FOUND
```

and the final result output as would look like:

```
ID      Company     Status
---------------------------
A3      company3    FOUND   
A5      company5    FOUND   
A7      company7    FOUND   
A8      company8    FOUND   
A10     company10   FOUND   
B100    B100        NOT FOUND
B200    B200        NOT FOUND
B400    B400        NOT FOUND
```

attention: `A5` and `A7` popped up in the first query result and also in the second one! so we need to keep only one.

some explanations if needed:
we get the list of unique `id`s from **table1** and their corresponding `company` from **table2**. We do a similar query for the second column of **table1**: we look up the values of the second column from **table1**, i.e. `name`, in the second column from **table2**, if we find it, then we get the corresponding `id` and `company` from **table2**, **but if that `id` already existed from our previous query then we drop it, no need to repeat it**. And third, if we don't find the values of `name` from **table1** in the `name` from **table2**, then we don't have any corresponding `id` nor `company`, so we attribute that `name` value both as `id` and `company`. And in general, if we found the `id`s and `name`s in **table1** from **table2** then we give them the status `FOUND` if not then, `NOT FOUND`.

thanks in advance

by the way, I have tried it with using `union` twice, but the query takes long time and it is not efficient.

Comment: do you mean only the titles should be capital letters? or something else?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos exactly, because we couldn't find any corresponding ID nor company, we attribute that name, i.e. B100 both as the ID and company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These requirements are confusing enough it might be worth a re-assessment of your data model.  I think the `UNION` solution is your best bet possibly modified to use `UNION ALL` for efficiency.

I did put together a mutex based hack that likely has as many subtle problems as any of the other queries on this page.

```
select
  coalesce(t2.id, t1.name) AS ID,
  coalesce(t2.company, t1.name) AS Company,
  if(isnull(t2.id), 'NOT FOUND', 'FOUND') as Status
from (select 0 as mutex union select 1) as m
left join table1 as t1 on 1 = 1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.name = t2.name or (t1.id = t2.id and mutex)
group by coalesce(t2.id, t1.name)
```

That said, please test these queries carefully and look over your data and results.  There's a whole lot of room for error depending on your input data.

Comment: your query is faster than Giorgos answer. so i accept it as the answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try with UNION DISTINCT like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id as ID,
        t2.company as Company,
        'FOUND' AS status
 FROM   table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2
          ON t1.id = t2.id
group by ID

union distinct

SELECT DISTINCT t2.id as ID,
        t2.company as Company,
        'FOUND' AS status
 FROM   table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2
          ON t1.name = t2.name
group by ID

union distinct

SELECT t1.name as ID,
        t1.name as Company,
        'NOT FOUND' AS status
 FROM   table1 t1
  WHERE  t1.name NOT IN (SELECT t2.name
                                FROM   table2 t2)
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: i know that this can be done with `union` but it is not efficient at all. it takes a lot of time.

Comment: FWIW, `UNION ALL` might be more efficient than `UNION` because it skips dupe elimination.  But it's not the approach I would use personally; you can also check out my suggested answer.

Comment: UNION ALL is more efficient but don't eliminate duplicates

Answer (score 2):

There's something unclear about your queries, because they shouldn't execute as you've shown them (due to `select` containing non-aggregates not in `group by`).  But based on your explanation of what you're trying to do...

You could use outer joins and then use case logic and/or coalesce to determine which value to use in each case.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       coalesce(t2_id.id, t2_name.id, t1.name) as ID
     , coalesce(t2_id.company, t2_name.company, t1.name) as Conpany
     , case when t2_id.id is not null or t2_name.name is not null
            then 'FOUND'
            else 'NOT FOUND'
       end status
  FROM           table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2_id
              ON t1.id = t2_id.id
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2_name
              ON t1.name = t2_name.name
```

Note that I used `DISTINCT` to make sure the exact same row doesn't appear multiple times; but this may return multiple rows for an ID (with different Company values) depending on the data.  I couldn't quite tell what was intended because the uses of `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the three queries as posted in the question didn't seem to add up for me.

Comment: ok let me  try your answer and then see what the group by is for.

Comment: actually i don't put those group by s, i only get one result! and if i include them, i get all of the results for that query.

Comment: actually the idea of using coalesce and case logic is nice, but it is returning a lot of duplicates. we want unique values.

Comment: Again I'm not sure the de-duping rules are clear to me, but if you can clarify them I can refine the query.  The simplest thing - if the dupes are the same in all fields then just say `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`, as in you original querys.

Comment: For the `GROUP BY` to behave as you described in your earlier comment, there must be something different about the query you're running vs the query you posted.  Perhaps were you using an aggregate function over the 2nd column (like MIN or MAX)?  That would be another deduping strategy that would make sure each ID only shows up once (and just picks one of the names to go with it)...

Comment: I only get "FOUND" rows running this query on the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(name2 IS NULL, name, ID) AS ID,
       IF(name2 IS NULL, name, Company) AS Company,
       IF(name2 IS NULL, 'NOT FOUND', 'FOUND') AS Status
FROM (       
   SELECT DISTINCT 
          CASE 
             WHEN t1.id = t2.id THEN t1.id 
             WHEN t1.name = t2.name THEN t2.id
             ELSE t1.id
          END AS ID, 
          CASE 
             WHEN t1.id = t2.id THEN t2.company
             WHEN t1.name = t2.name THEN t2.company
             ELSE t1.name
          END AS Company,
          t1.name,
          (SELECT Table2.name
           FROM Table2
           WHERE Table2.name = t1.name LIMIT 1) AS name2
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) OR (t1.name = t2.name)) AS t
ORDER BY ID;
```

The query use a single `LEFT JOIN` operation plus a correlated subquery.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41ea0/1)

Comment: It seems like you'd have to join `Table1` again in some cases to have both FOUND and NOT FOUND.  For example if you NULL Table2's "B3" cell then ID "A7" comes up missing in the final result.

Comment: this is amazing! thanks. Is it possible to add the count of each to another column? http://i.imgur.com/DLXmBM3.png here is what it would like. Counting the times the IDs get repeated in column1-table1 and adding to that count, the number of times "name" (which has its corresponding ID in column1) gets repeated, if it doesn't have corresponding ID, then it gets counted itself the number of times it is repeated in the second column of table1.

Comment: @marcel Well, that's a different question. Try writing a separate post for this requirement.

Comment: @ebyrob After a closer look, it turns out your remark is not correct. In the case you mention none of the three queries cited in the OP would return record of `table1` with `Id=A7`.

Comment: i posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260507/sql-get-the-count-for-two-columns-left-joined-from-two-tables

Comment: i still have another small question related to this query, how and where in the code should i add a `WHERE id IN ('A3','A5')` for example. trying to filter only `A3` and `A5`, meaning that that query will turn results if the id or the corresponding id of the name is in this list. thanks in advance.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It seems clear to me Query1 `SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON id` would include a record with ID "A7" if both table1 and table2 contain ID="A7".