# sql get the count for two columns left joined from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Following [Giorgos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41248290/6931572) to my previous question, I want to add an extra column to the results table.
This column will hold the frequency of occurrence of `ID`.
and the results will be like this:

```
ID  Company         status          Freq      
---------------------------------------
A10     company10   FOUND           1
A3      company3    FOUND           2
A5      company5    FOUND           3
A7      company7    FOUND           2
A8      company8    FOUND           3
B100    B100        NOT FOUND       1
B200    B200        NOT FOUND       1
B400    B400        NOT FOUND       1
```

some explanations on how to get the count of the frequency:
The count is the sum total of the times the ID occurs in column `id` from Table1 plus the number of times the corresponding `name` of the same `id` appears in the `name` column of table1. 
Or in another scenario, the `name` has a corresponding `id` in table2, then if that id is available in the table1, then we add to the count of that existing id, if not, we include that id and count the times the corresponding name occurred in table1. 
**and in another scenario**, if the corresponding id of that name not found, then count the number of the occurrences of that particular name in the table1.
**For example**, A3 occurs twice in table1, and none of the names in column2 of table1 has a corresponding id that is A3, so A3 gets the count of 2.
**another example**: A5 occurs one time in column1 in table1, but its corresponding name in table2, which is B2, it occurs twice in the second column of table1, so we add these two counts, and A5 gets 3.
**another example**, we don't have A10 in table1, but it appears in results, because one of the names in column2-table1,which is B6, has a corresponding id of A10, so instead of creating an entry for B6 and adding its count, we take the id from table2 and add to its count.
**another example**, if the name doesn't have a corresponding id in table2, like B400, then we put it as an entry in the results table and count the times it occurred in table1, and in this example, it occurred once.

here is the [demo of existing example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41ea0/9/0) but without the counts.
and some more explanations on how the current results table is built:
we get the list of unique ids from table1 and their corresponding company from table2. We do a similar query for the second column of table1: we look up the values of the second column from table1, i.e. name, in the second column from table2, if we find it, then we get the corresponding id and company from table2, but if that id already existed from our previous query then we drop it, no need to repeat it. And third, if we don't find the values of name from table1 in the name from table2, then we don't have any corresponding id nor company, so we attribute that name value both as id and company. And in general, if we found the ids and names in table1 from table2 then we give them the status FOUND if not then, NOT FOUND.

and the sql query used to get the current results table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(name2 IS NULL, name, ID) AS ID,
       IF(name2 IS NULL, name, Company) AS Company,
       IF(name2 IS NULL, 'NOT FOUND', 'FOUND') AS Status
FROM (       
   SELECT DISTINCT 
          CASE 
             WHEN t1.id = t2.id THEN t1.id 
             WHEN t1.name = t2.name THEN t2.id
             ELSE t1.id
          END AS ID, 
          CASE 
             WHEN t1.id = t2.id THEN t2.company
             WHEN t1.name = t2.name THEN t2.company
             ELSE t1.name
          END AS Company,
          t1.name,
          (SELECT Table2.name
           FROM Table2
           WHERE Table2.name = t1.name LIMIT 1) AS name2
   FROM Table1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) OR (t1.name = t2.name)) AS t
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Please edit your question so those who do not know your previous answer may follow.

Comment: Link to your demo does not work. Check if it is correct.